# list containing data from firebase database not displayed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a Snapchat clone. I'm stuck at the part where the activity is supposed to display a list of email ids of users who have sent snaps to the current user.In fact the message is not even getting logged into logcat. Here is the code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blank);
         list=findViewById(R.id.emails);
        id=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> ada=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,id);
        list.setAdapter(ada);
        try {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("snaps").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    Log.i("first", "created");

                    Log.i("pug", dataSnapshot.child("from").getValue().toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("error",e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the database
 [image]

Comment: add a screenshot or ur database

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the database @AlexMamo

Comment: @PeterHaddad the picture has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database structure, it shows that you are not using the uid, instead you are using a random id generated using the `push()` method, you need to add data using the `uid` instead to be able to access it when retrieving.

Comment: Is there any way I can access the id generated using push? @PeterHaddad

Comment: when adding data you can do `String key = dbRef.getKey();`, and pass it using sharedpreference or intent, but now in your code if you want to access  `push()` your going to add more than one eventlistener

Comment: I did as you suggested and replaced all push with strings generated using UUid function but problem still seems unsolved @PeterHaddad

Comment: Do u have users>uid>snaps>randomid>data now?

Comment: No I'm still not getting the required data in the Logcat. I found this in the Logcat-W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@3b1ee6. Is this of any relevance to our problem? @PeterHaddad

Comment: i mean in ur db is the structure like this `users>uid>snaps>randomid>data`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really new to this so I'm not sure..I've added a new picture of the changed database.Could you please check it? @PeterHaddad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213439/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-akul-shivakumar).